# What `chkdsk` verifies and what it does not verify?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, storage, chkdsk

What kind of problems [`chkdsk`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk) can identify? Are there any disk problems that `chkdsk` cannot identify and will mark a malfunctioning storage device as a healthy one? Are there cases when I would need to use other tools to check disks for logical or physical errors?

Comment: @moab I am assuming that it checks the hardware, too because the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk) says "_... for logical and **physical** errors_". Therefore, I still think that `chkdsk` checks the hardware.

Comment: @moab what about bad sectors? `chkdsk /r`

Comment: I edited my answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

If you run it it will tell you what it does, it checks the file system.

If you add the F or R switch it will require a reboot, then along with the file system it will read every sector on the disk to verify the integity of the read surface and attempt to fix that sector (recover data) or replace the sector with a spare and mark the bad one so it does not get used again.

This is a check of the physical health of the drive surfaces only but is not a full disk diagnostic.

Reading the SMART data on the drive is a better indication of overall drive health, and chkdsk does not do this.

> CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 3)...
> 272384 file records processed.
> File verification completed.
> 1371 large file records processed.
> 0 bad file records processed.
> 2 EA records processed.
> 11218 reparse records processed.

> CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 3)...
> 344952 index entries processed.
> Index verification completed.
> 0 unindexed files scanned.
> 0 unindexed files recovered.

> CHKDSK is verifying security descriptors (stage 3 of 3)...
> 272384 file SDs/SIDs processed.
> Security descriptor verification completed.
> 36285 data files processed.

> CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
> 33879688 USN bytes processed.
> Usn Journal verification completed.
> Windows has checked the file system and found no problems.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not want to upvote or accept your answer because your answers were initially incorrect and you fixed that only after my comments. Moreover, you deleted your invalid comments.